# Efficient way to implement "change to other number" in a Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

## Question

Suppose I now have an array that looks like `arr = np.random.randint(1, 4, 100)`, where the unique numbers are 1, 2, and 3.

Now I would like to model the *data corruption*, where some of the numbers are likely to become others. For example, if `arr[k]` is 1, then it is likely to remain the same, but it is also possible to become 2 or 3 (all with equal probabilities).

I could implement this using following code

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randint(1, 4, 100)

mask = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=100, p=[0.8, 0.2])
for idx in range(100):
    if mask[idx] != 0:
        arr[idx] = np.random.choice([1, 2, 3)
```

This works fine but I really do not like the loop. Is there some way I could eliminate the (ugly) loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works fine

```
np.where(np.random.choice([1,0],100, p=[0.8,0.2]), arr, np.random.randint(1,4,100))
```

To compute the final proportion of corruption

```
y = np.where(np.random.choice([1,0],100, p=[0.8,0.2]), arr, np.random.randint(1,4,100))
(arr != y).mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randint(1, 4, 100)
arr2 = np.random.randint(1, 4, 100)
mask = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=100, p=[0.8, 0.2]) != 0
arr[mask] = arr2[mask]
```

Alternatively, you can count how many `True`s there are in `mask` and just make `arr2` precisely that many elements long.

Comment: Your suggestion is the more efficient option